# re-throwing RuntimeExceptions

Tags: exception

In my code, I usually re-throw checked exceptions wrapped around an RuntimeException. I do this when I can't do much about the exception, but I also don't want add throws in my method's signature.

So what I end up doing is:

```
try {
  // code that may throw exception
}
catch (Exception e) {
  throw new RuntimeException(e)
}
```

This is too verbose and reduces readability.
I tried to write a helper method like this:

```
  public void ignoreException(Runnable runnable) {
    try {
      runnable.run();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
```

and then call it like that:

```
  public static void main() {
    ignoreExcceptions(() -> Thread.sleep(1000));
  }
```

but it (of course) doesn't bypasses the compiler's checks for exceptions.

Is there any way to do this wrapping thing in a less verbose and more readable way?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved this:

```
public interface NonReturningCallable {

  public void call() throws Exception;

}

import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class ExceptionUtils {

  public static void checkExceptions(NonReturningCallable callable) {
    try {
      callable.call();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  public static <V> V checkExceptions(Callable<V> callable) {
    try {
      return callable.call();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
}

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExceptionUtils.checkExceptions(() -> Thread.sleep(1000));
    int a = ExceptionUtils.checkExceptions(() -> Math.min(1, 2));
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I had to declare my own NonReturningCallable interface since I couldn't find one in the JDK library.